# How I can remove double lines in whole file, omiting first n characters in each line?

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

I have following data format:

```
123456786|data1
123456787|data2
123456788|data3
```

The first column is main_id. I need to remove all duplicated lines from txt file but omitting main_id number. How I can do that?

Normally I use such AWK script, but it finds double lines without omiting:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' $2 > "$filename"_no_doublets.txt #remove doublets
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F'|' '!x[$2]++'
```

This will find duplicates only based on field 2 delimited by `|`

**UPDATE:**

```
awk '{line=$0; sub(/^[^|]+\|/, "", line)} !found[line]++'
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I have several columns after main_id column and I want to find duplicated comparing line by line without main_id first column?

Comment: @Kent: Thakks, yes great minds think a like :) +1 to you answer as well.

Comment: And now Ed also thought on same lines that validates our thought processes :)

Comment: Yeah, I was just late to the party. I'd delete mine but I think having meaningful words for the variable names might be useful and I have a slight preference for the RE I used in the sub().

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton I updated with meaningful variable names as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

if you have more columns, this line should do:

```
awk '{a=$0;sub(/[^|]*\|/,"",a)}!x[a]++' file
```

example:

```
123456786|data1
12345676|data1
123456787|data2|foo
203948787|data2|foo
123456788|data3

kent$  awk '{a=$0;sub(/[^|]*\|/,"",a)}!x[a]++' f
123456786|data1
123456787|data2|foo
123456788|data3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{key=$0; sub(/[^|]+/,"",key)} !seen[key]++' file
```